# EASTL vector-design on size() method

Tags: c++, vector, eastl

I have a question on the implementation of vector in `EASTL`.
The link is [here.](https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/vector.h)

Namely, on the method `size()`. Here is what it looks like:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator>
inline typename vector<T, Allocator>::size_type
vector<T, Allocator>::size() const
{
    return (size_type)(mpEnd - mpBegin);  
}
```

`size_type` is `uint32_t`, `mpBegin`/`mpEnd` are T* pointers.

I do not understand how the cast to uint32_t from (mpEnd - mpBegin) equals the **number** of elements in a vector. Shouldn't it be divided by `sizeof(T)`? Otherwise we just get the size in bytes of all the elements in the vector?

What am I missing?

EDIT: Unless, the EASTL vector dosn't follow the stl defintion of a vector, but I couldn't find any data on it and its supposedly be possible to replace stl vector with eastl vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the cast that causes the operation to equal the number of elements in the array.  Pointer subtraction already does the right thing here.  When you subtract one pointer from another, the size of the types they point to is taken into account.  There is no need to divide by `sizeof(T)`.  It has always been this way, even in C.  The cast simply converts it to the right integer type for the return value, if it's not already.

Answer (score 1):

The size is only in bytes if you are using `char*` or possibly `void*`. Else, it is in `sizeof(T)`. Since `mpEnd` and `mpBegin` are `T*`.

Comment: `void*` doesn’t allow pointer arithmetic. And even with `char*` it’s still in units of `sizeof(T)`, which just happens to be 1.